# How to use an Azure Function (Python) as a HTTP dataset in an Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I keep getting connection timeouts when I try to create a dataset (HTTP) in  an Azure Data Factory which is based on a Azure Function (HTTP trigger):

```
  The cloud service request timed out. Please retry. Activity ID:9d70efcd-c842-4484-9313-4872208a2a9e
```

However, if I call function from anywhere else e.g. from [apitester.com](https://apitester.com/shared/checks/d6108814e83149b4baee7f2b60786c82), I get the desired response:

- Request URL: https://srf-scadapa-fa2-windows.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerPython32?code=L5WVNJh8loDv3mZFcD/AKatNRoYfYoHlDbEBk4AEGrbDA39ddAXsyg==
- Request method: post
- Request body: { "group_name": "Azure POC" }
- Response body:

  {"timestamp":"2018-09-24 14:23:42","python_version":"3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]"}

The source code of the function HttpTriggerPython32 is as follows:

```
import os, sys, json
from datetime import datetime

postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())

responseData = {
    'timestamp' : datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Zurich")).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    'python_version' : sys.version
}

response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
response.write(str(responseData))
```

I've successfully added other 3rd party HTTP services as datasets in the data factory. Also, I've managed to call the function by using a Web activity.
The error only occurs when I try to use the function as a dataset source.

To add the function as data factory dataset I created a new dataset with the following parameters:

```
{
    "name": "HttpFile1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AF_srfscadapa_af1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "HttpFile",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "filePattern": "setOfObjects"
            },
            "relativeUrl": "HttpTriggerPython32?code=L5WVNJh8loDv3mZFcD/AKatNRoYfYoHlDbEBk4AEGrbDA39ddAXsyg==",
            "requestMethod": "Post",
            "requestBody": "{\n    \"group_name\": \"Azure POC\"\n}"
        }
    }
}
```

The linked service "AF_srfscadapa_af1" is configured as follows:

- Connect via integration runtime: AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime
- Base URL: https://srf-scadapa-fa2-windows.azurewebsites.net/api/
- Server Certificate Validation: False
- Authentification type: Anonymous

Comment: Have you tried different timeout values for your Http activity? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#copy-activity-properties.

Comment: I am not super familiar with Azure Data Factory (I am on the Functions team), but is it possible that your linked service is having issues because the base URL returns a 404? Maybe try making your base URL https://srf-scadapa-fa2-windows.azurewebsites.net and editing your relative URL accordingly?

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon Thanks, I managed to solve it using the timeout setting parameter in the copy activity

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions (along with pretty much all serverless platforms) has to deal with the cold-start latency problem, where the first request to a function application after a period of no use takes longer. This is because the platform needs to instantiate an instance of your application before servicing the request. This can add a non-trivial amount of time to a request, which could have increased your latency over what is allowed by the default timeout for Azure Data Lake.

According to the [documentation for Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#copy-activity-properties), Copy Activities with HTTP as a source have a timeout field. Configuring this to a higher value may fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Manually defining all the columns of the source and increasing the timeout in the copy activity solved the problem.

I was using the Data Factory GUI where it's not possible to set a timeout for previewing a source or importing a schema. So in this particular case the "Import schema" function simply does not work.